# How to create optional XML tag with attribute inside XML forest

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g

I am stuck with a problem with creating XML in Oracle.

I managed to create XML structure like provided below:

```
<A>
   <B attr1="1">
      10
   </B>
</A>
```

It should return null when value of B is NULL. This can be done with such piece of code:

```
SELECT
    XMLForest(
        CASE 
            WHEN t.V IS NOT NULL
            THEN
                XMLElement(
                    "B",
                    XMLAttributes(
                        t.A1 as attr1
                    ),
                    t.V
                )
        END as A
    ) as testa
FROM
(
    SELECT
        10 as V,
        1 as A1
    FROM
        dual
) t
;
```

But I can not think of anything that will generate structure like this:

```
<A>
   <B attr1="1">
      10
   </B>
   <C>
      2
   </C>
</A>
```

which should return NULL if values of both B and C are NULLs. And in reality A element is child in other XMLForest, so encasing it in big CASE is not an option.

Would appreciate some help here...

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find a solution using [XMLConcat](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10790/xdb13gen.htm#i1032050) function. It looks like this:

```
SELECT
    XMLForest(
        CASE 
            WHEN t.V IS NOT NULL OR t.C IS NOT NULL
            THEN XMLConcat(
                XMLElement(
                    "B",
                    XMLAttributes(
                        t.A1 as attr1
                    ),
                    t.V
                ),
                XMLElement(
                    "C",
                    t.C
                )                                
            )
        END as A
    ) as testa
FROM
(
    SELECT
        10 as V,
        1 as A1,
        NULL as C
    FROM
        dual
) t
;
```